# openstack newbie: why give me this error, even if password is correct?

Tags: openstack

I have installed openstack following [this guide.](https://www.tecmint.com/openstack-installation-guide-rhel-centos/)

Now I want to try a simple cli command

```
openstack catalog list
```

I have export all this variables

```
export HOSTNAME="openstack1"
export OS_AUTH_PLUGIN="token"
export OS_AUTH_URL="http://openstack1:5000/v3/"
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION="3"
export OS_PASSWORD="correctadminpass"
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID="default"
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME="mydomain.fqdn"
export OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT="http://openstack1:5000/v3/"
export OS_SERVICE_TOKEN="1234tokencorrecttakefromkeystone.conf"
export OS_USERNAME="admin"
```

But the command return this error

```
openstack  catalog list
The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-3346b80c-0b57-4a7e-a8c9-cf07acb83976)
```

Is not sufficient to export the OS variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found, the command

```
openstack catalog list
```

return correct output after exporting those variables

```
export OS_AUTH_URL="http://openstack1.mydomain.priv:5000/v3"
export OS_BOOTSTRAP_PASSWORD="mypass"
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION="3"
export OS_PASSWORD="mypass"
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID="default"
export OS_PROJECT_NAME="admin"
export OS_TENANT_NAME="admin"
export OS_USERNAME="admin"
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_ID="default"
```

Answer (score 2):

It gave you the error because the project was not specified.  Openstack authentication requires a username or id, *and* a project name or id.

Note that:

```
export OS_PROJECT_NAME="admin"
export OS_TENANT_NAME="admin"
```

are effectively saying the same thing.  "Tenant" is the old terminology for "project".

Please refer to the [Openstack command Manual Entry](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/stein/cli/man/openstack.html#environment-variables) for more details on the environment variables that it recognizes.

Normally, the only URL you need is the URL for Keystone (OS_AUTH_URL).  The `openstack` command can work out how to contact other services from the Keystone catalog.